# How to perform right click with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless-browser

I'm trying to perform right-click with Puppeteer.

I've tried to add the option:

```
await component.click({ button: "right" })
```

But all I get is a regular click on the component. I followed Puppeteer's [API](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Code seems OK, so without seeing the component hard to say why it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is correct that you can use [`elementHandle.click()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleclickoptions) with the `button` option set to `'right'` to right-click an element:

```
const example = await page.$('#example');

await example.click({
  button: 'right',
});
```

According to the Official Documentation for `elementHandle.click()`:

> This method scrolls element into view if needed, and then uses [`page.mouse`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagemouse) to click in the center of the element. If the element is detached from DOM, the method throws an error.

We can verify this by looking at the [source code for `mouse.click()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/3d7ae2a2591a55e4f94c67d62a22f7103698cba5/lib/Input.js#L225), and we can see that the `button` option is considered before being sent to [`Input.dispatchMouseEvent`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Input#method-dispatchMouseEvent) in the Chrome DevTools Protocol.

Another method you can use to right-click an element would be to use use [`page.click()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options):

```
await page.click('#example', {
  button: 'right',
});
```

Alternatively, you can use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to right-click an element with JavaScript executed in the page DOM environment:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const example = document.getElementById('example');
  const event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');

  event.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 2, null);

  example.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use mouse,

```
 await page.mouse.click(160, 300, {delay: 1000, button: 'left'});
```

you can do this ya